# System string2.h header file generates a compilation error when optimizing

Tags: c, optimization, ubuntu, gcc, embedded-linux

I am running **Linaro Ubuntu 12.03** on an embedded platform. After using this system for a few months for building a simple program, I started receiving a compilation error when adding an optimization option. So, I created a test program:

```
// test.c
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

compiling with:

```
gcc test.c
```

works just fine. However, when I add an optimization option:

```
gcc -O1 test.c
```

I get an error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:637:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi/bits/string2.h:1305:3: error: "(" may not appear in macro parameter list
```

This happens for all levels from `-O1` to `-Ofast`.

Trying the same on another embedded system with **Linaro Ubuntu 12.04**, it works just fine. So does it on my Ubuntu PC.

The code section in `string2.h`:

```
#  define __strdup(sp \
  (__extension__ (__builtin_constant_p (s) && __string2_1bptr_p (s)       \
          ? (((__const char *) (s))[0] == '\0'                \
             ? (char *) calloc ((size_t) 1, (size_t) 1)           \
             : ({ size_t __len = strlen (s) + 1;              \
              char *__retval = (char *) malloc (__len);       \
              if (__retval != NULL)                   \
                __retval = (char *) memcpy (__retval, s, __len);  \
              __retval; }))                       \
          : __strdup (s)))
```

(the problem is in the 2nd line of the macro)

**Why did my build environment stop working with no apparent reason?**

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I just examined the same file on another board running 12.03, as well as the one on the 12.04 system. It looks like there is indeed a syntax error in the `string2.h` file on the 1st board. The two other files show:

```
#  define __strdup(s) \
```

instead of:

```
#  define __strdup(sp \
```

so it the `)` was replaced with `p`. The only explanation I can think of now is that the SD card I am using starts to corrupt files. However, any other explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Superficially, it appears that the `string2.h` you are using doesn't agree with the C compiler you are using.  Changing the optimization level should not affect the validity of C code in general.  Did you change the compiler recently?  Or the header files?

Comment: No, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Could be a hardware problem possibly of the storage media.

Comment: Yes, seems to be so. Look at the update.

Comment: Another possibility is that `string2.h` was never written correctly onto the SD when it was installed and you only found out about it now by exercising the optimizations.  If you were using the optimizations before, then definitely there's something going on with the card (or the hardware that accesses the card).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - you are right that the optimization level should not affect the preprocessing. So, why doesn't it fail when I don't use optimization?

Comment: NVM - looking at the `string.h` relevant location, the inclusion of this header actually does depend on optimization.

Comment: @ldav1s - I used the same build script hundreds of times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it used to work in the past and `string2.h` changed on the SD card, it's likely that there's a bad sector in the SD card at the least.